# Creating an an embedded image link that returns a parameter andredirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I have so far:

```
<`%= link_to image_tag("category_images/beef.jpg"),(:category => "beef"),
    http://localhost:3000/food/beef" %>`
```

I've tried a multitude of variations on this idea and have been scouring the internet for potential solutions but everything seems to fail with regards to implementing all the mentioned requirements?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please expand the meaning of "answering the parameter"?

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect", is that another way of saying "the place I want the link to point to"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "http://localhost:3000/food/beef?#{ { category: "beef" }.to_param }" do %>
  <% image_tag("category_images/beef.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```